# Is it possible to implement Hands free call using Dialogflow for Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, api-ai

I have some requirement to develop a Hands free call using Dialog-flow with/without using third party apps.Is it possible to implement business services using custom skill for Hands free calls from Google Home.Whether this kind of permission is provided from  Google Home or not?

If their means can i have a sample/example related to above requirment

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Google (and I don't speak for them) does not publish an API for making calls the way the Home devices do. The best that you can do is to put a link on a button on a basic card or have a suggestion link that references the "tel:" scheme.